# JAX-RS provider registered but never invoked or called

Tags: jackson, cxf, fasterxml

Although we specify Jackson as jax-rs provider in blueprint.xml, we dont find it being invoked/called to convert our POJO to JSON. We use 
CXF version - 3.0.3
Karaf version - 3.0.3

```
<jaxrs:server address="/test" id="totest">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref component-id="testREST"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
                <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
        </jaxrs:providers>   
    </jaxrs:server>
```

We get following exception, we observe org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider being called.

```
  at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.handleExceptionEnd(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:719)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.handleJAXBException(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:743)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider.writeTo(JSONProvider.java:395)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.writeMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1363)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor.serializeMessage(JAXRSOutInterceptor.java:244)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor.processResponse(JAXRSOutInterceptor.java:117)
```

**Updated Information**

```
POM.xml with all related jars as dependency.

        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                <version>20131018</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Thanks

Comment: do you still get the same error?

Comment: Yes. I have included all the jars as dependency.

Comment: Only adding compile time dependencies via pom.xml is not enough. You will need to tell the application server also where to pick up jars from at runtime. Which application server are you using?

Comment: Since all these jackson jars are installed in KARAF as part of other features, we mentioned the scope as "Provided". Please let us know if our understanding is incorrect.

Comment: which applications server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide all jackson related jars to the server - either as part of WEB-INF/lib of your web project, or as a server library, or as a module. It appears that you currently only have cxf.jar which is why jackson packaged within it is getting picked up. When you run the application on the server, at the time the execution thread reaches your jackson annotations, it tries to find the corresponding jars at runtime. The only related jar it can find then seems to be cxf.